# How to traverse a query result in python?

Tags: python, tuples

This is a general question, consider I have a table with a number of columns like:

```
serial_number    time          number_1    number2
1                14:00:00       123             124
2                13:00:34       121             11111
```

with a million rows. I want to get the result of a query like:

```
SELECT * from table if time = "14:00:00";
```

the result of this is a tuple of tuples, how will I traverse the result and process it in python, can you please point to me some on doing this.

Comment: Wait you have a plain text file? Or a sql table? and is the question after you grab the data? What does `list[0]` look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General question - general answer. You can traverse anything in Python using *iteration*:

```
for row in c.execute('SELECT * from table if time = "14:00:00"').fetchall():
    print row
```

Comment: @bernie's edit: Note that you don't have to do a `fetchall()` if you don't want to necessarily pre-fetch all the data. In fact, for million-row query results it makes more sense to read data incrementally.

Comment: I do not want to print the value in the tuples, but use it assign these two a set of variables. I am able to print it, but I dont know how to traverse the tuple of tuples and select column values for different rows and process it.                                                                                                                                                                                                             ((1, 12, test), (2, 12, test), (3, 13, test1)) `code` How to fetch the sum of second column of all these rows.

Comment: You can traverse the tuple using (badum-tss) iteration (e.g. an internal for-loop). You can access elements of a tuple using the `row[i]` syntax. As for summing all values in the second column, this is probably best done from within the SQL statement.

Comment: The first [google link](http://blogs.wrox.com/article/using-the-python-database-apis/) for the query "Python database API" might be something you should read through, perhaps.

Comment: this resource is really awesome http://blogs.wrox.com/article/using-the-python-database-apis/ , thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this is what you're looking for:

```
c.execute("SELECT serial_number, time, number_1, number2 FROM table WHERE time = '14:00:00'")

sum_number_1 = 0
for serial_number, time, number_1, number2 in c:
    print serial_number, time, number_1, number2
    sum_number_1 += number_1

print sum_number_1
```

Cursor iterator support for DB API v2.0 clients is optional (http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#optional-db-api-extensions) but mostly supported. I tested it with psycopg2.

Answer (score 0):

I have mentioned this in a comment to @KT , just make it clear, this article http://blogs.wrox.com/article/using-the-python-database-apis/ from the book Using Python 2.6 and Python 3.1 by James Payne is the best resource on this topic that I have read till date.